# Comunicacion entre componentes de Vue en formularios

Tags: vue.js

Estoy empezando con vue y nose si mi logica de usar los componentes es la correcta

Tengo un componente que es un select con informacion de un catalogo (selectGlobal.vue), este componente lo utilizare en varios formularios (formulario.vue), mi pregunta es como leer el dato seleccionado en el select, si lo hago con un v-model por alguna razon sale vacio, si lo hago con jquery ($('#xxxx').val()) si obtiene el dato que se necesita

Componente select (este se reutilizara en multiples formularios)

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option v-for="item in arrayCategorias" :value="item.id" v-text="item.categoria"></option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "g-select-categorias",
        data(){
            return {
                categoria: '',
                arrayCategorias: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            listar(){
                var me = this;
                var url = '/categorias';
                axios.get(url)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        me.arrayCategorias = response.data.categorias;
                    });
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.listar();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Componente formulario

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label for="cbCategoria">Categoria</label>
                <gSelectCategorias id="cbCategoria" v-model="categoria"></gSelectCategorias>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="agregar()">Agregar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import gSelectCategorias from './globales/gSelectCategorias.vue'
    export default {
        name: "xxxx",
        components: {
            gSelectCategorias
        },
        data(){
            return{
                categoria: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            agregar(){
                console.info('Agregar');
                console.info(this.categoria);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, lo primero que tienes que saber es que la forma de pasar valores desde un componente hijo a un padre en Vue.js es a travez de `Custom Events`, lo segundo es que para poder usar `v-model` en `Custom Components` o `Custom Inputs` lo que tienes que hacer es enlazar la propiedad `value` del componente hijo al valor del select y a la vez en el mismo componente emitir el evento `input` con el nuevo valor del select, entonces esté evento `input` actualizará el valor que tienes en `v-model` del componente padre .

Ya en la práctica y usando tu mismo ejemplo, tu componente hijo tendría que quedar algo así, espero sirva de ayuda:

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" @change="updateValue($event.target.value)">
        <option v-for="item in arrayCategorias" :value="item.id" v-text="item.categoria"></option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ["value"]
        name: "g-select-categorias",
        data(){
            return {
                categoria: '',
                arrayCategorias: ''
            }
        },
        computed: {
          selected: {
           get: function() {
            return this.value;
           },
           set: function() {}
          },
        },
        methods: {
            listar(){
                var me = this;
                var url = '/categorias';
                axios.get(url)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        me.arrayCategorias = response.data.categorias;
                    });
            },
            updateValue(value) {
               this.$emit("input", value);
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.listar();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Referencias:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristopher, encontre algo parecido a lo que me comentas y en el componente hijo en la etiqueta select agregue: `@input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"` y con eso funciono.

Comment: Excelente, sip, es prácticamente lo mismo. Saludos!